# What are the steps to be taken in the initial projects in Software Companies?

Tags: team-management, software-development, planning, product-management

I'm working in the middle level of a software company. My role is a software developer. I don't know what processes are to be handled in the Software Development company?

Can you explain me in detail? So many hierarchies are used in the Software Developement companies (i.e CMM Level Companies). Now I have 5 years of experience in software development, but I don't know what are the steps to be intially taken in the Software Development Companies. What are the designs handled in the Software Development companies?

Comment: Hi Adalarasan, welcome to PMSE! It's not clear exactly what you're asking, and your questions are really broad and vague. There are many different software methodologies, so many that several books have been written on these subject. We're closing this for now, but if you feel you do have a more *specific* question hiding in there or a specific problem you've encountered in your 5 years working on projects, please feel free to make an [edit] to your question and leave a comment and flag asking for a review. Welcome to PMSE! Good luck!

Comment: I agree, not clear what help you're expecting. If you're developer, you should develop. If you need help, you ask your PM, because she or he should know about initializing the project. Note that not initializing the project due to other priorities is a very bad thing to do. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean steps like:

- Define vision
- Research business
- Implement document version control
- Research initial requirements
- Write initial requirements
- Research high level architecture
- Write high level architecture
- Implement source version control
- Implement build and test server
- Perform iterations of collect requirements, design, code tests, optimize process